# Variation of the metric with respect to the metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, variational-calculus, degrees-of-freedom

For a variation of the metric $g^{\mu\nu}$ with respect to $g^{\alpha\beta}$ you might expect the result (at least I did):

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}= \delta_\mu^\alpha\delta_\nu^\beta.
\end{equation}

but then to preserve the fact that $g^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric under interchange of $\mu$ and $\nu$ we should probably symmetrise the right hand side like this:

\begin{equation}\frac{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}= \delta_\mu^\alpha\delta_\nu^\beta + \delta_\mu^\beta\delta_\nu^\alpha.\end{equation}

Is this reasonable/correct? If not, why not?

It seems that I can derive some weird results if this is right (or maybe I'm just making other mistakes).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the metric $g_{\mu\nu}=g_{\nu\mu}$ is symmetric, we must demand that

$$\begin{align} \delta g_{\mu\nu}~=~&\delta g_{\nu\mu}\cr~=~&\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta g_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\nu\mu}\right)\cr~=~&\frac{1}{2}\left( \delta_{\mu}^{\alpha}\delta_{\nu}^{\beta} + \delta_{\nu}^{\alpha}\delta_{\mu}^{\beta}\right)\delta g_{\alpha\beta},\end{align}\tag{1}$$

and therefore

$$ \frac{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}
~=~\frac{1}{2}\left( \delta_{\mu}^{\alpha}\delta_{\nu}^{\beta} + \delta_{\nu}^{\alpha}\delta_{\mu}^{\beta}\right).\tag{2}$$

The price we pay to treat the matrix entries $g_{\alpha\beta}$ as $n^2$ independent variables (as opposed to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ symmetric elements) is that there appears a half in the off-diagonal variations.

Another check of the formalism is that the RHS and LHS of eq. (2) should be [idempotents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) because of the chain rule. For further motivation, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405495/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I also considered this, but consider

$\frac{\delta g^{12}}{\delta g^{12}} = \frac{1}{2}(\delta^1_1\delta^2_2 + \delta^1_2\delta^2_1) = \frac{1}{2}$

Would I not expect to get 1?

Comment: Thank you, I had to think about it for a while but it makes sense now :)

Comment: Hey, Sam. I got linked to this question from a similar one I had: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335173/. 

I still don't quite get the issue with the factors of $\frac{1}{2}$. Why did it eventually make sense to you that $\frac{\partial g^{12}}{\partial g^{12}} = \frac{1}{2}$? That just looks so wrong to me.

Comment: The point is that the two elements $g_{12}=g_{21}$ are equal, so they cannot be varied independently. If you (wrongly) think that $\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial g_{12}}$ should be $1$, while $\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial g_{12}}$ should be $0$, then recall that they are actually equal $\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial g_{12}}=\frac{\partial g_{21}}{\partial g_{12}}$!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be - adapted to the case of symmetric matrices in the OP but also valid for general symmetric arrays as well as in many other contexts - to consider the space $S^2_n$ of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices, viewed as the coordinate space $S^2_n=\mathbb R^{n(n+1)/2}$ with standard coordinates $$(s^{ij})_{i\le j}=(s^{11},s^{12},...,s^{1n},s^{22},s^{23},...,s^{33},s^{34},...),$$ and thus a function $f(s)=f(s^{11},s^{12},...,s^{1n},s^{22},s^{23},...)$ does not depend on any of the $s^{ji}$ ($i<j$) because those are not actually coordinates on $S^2_n$.

Also define $T^2_n$ to be the space of $n\times n$ matrices, viewed as $T^2_n=\mathbb R^{n^2}$, with (unrestricted) coordinates $$(x^{ij})_{i,j=1,...,n}=(x^{11},...,x^{1n},x^{21},...).$$

In this approach, $S^2_n$ is not a subspace of $T^2_n$, but we can define two maps, an *inclusion* $\imath:S^2_n\rightarrow T^2_n$ and a *projection*/*symmetrization* $\sigma:T^2_n\rightarrow S^2_n$, defined as follows.

If $s=(s^{ij})_{i\le j}$, then $x^{ij}=\imath(s)^{ij}$ is defined as $$x^{ij}=\left\{\begin{matrix} s^{ij} & i\le j \\ s^{ji} & i>j\end{matrix}\right. ,$$ i.e. it is the natural extension of $(s^{ij})_{i\le j}$ into a symmetric array, while the projection/symmetrization is defined as - if $s=\sigma(x)$ - so that $$ s^{ij}=x^{(ij)}=\frac{1}{2}(x^{ij}+x^{ji}),\ i\le j, $$ i.e. we first symmetrize $x^{ij}$, and the restrict the value of the indices so that $i\le j$.

Clearly $\sigma$ is a left inverse of $\imath$ in the sense that $\sigma\circ\imath=\mathrm{Id}_{S^2_n}$.

---

We can now consider tangent vectors on $S^2_n$ and $T^2_n$, on the former a generic tangent vector has the form $$ v=\sum_{i\le j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{ij}}|_s \in T_sS^2_n,$$ whereas on the latter we have $$ w=\sum_{i,j}w^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}|_x\in T_xT^2_n. $$

We attempt to relate derivatives with respect to the restricted variables $s^{ij}$ to derivatives with respect to the unrestricted variables $x^{ij}$ by noting that for any vector $v\in T_sS^2_n$ and function $f\in C^\infty(S^2_n)$ we have $$ v(f)=v(f\circ\sigma\circ\imath)=\imath_\ast(v)(\sigma^\ast f), $$ where $\imath_\ast$ is pushforward along the inclusion and $\sigma^\ast$ is pullback along the symmetrization.

We have $$ (\sigma^\ast f)(x)=(f\circ\sigma)(x)=f(\sigma(x)). $$ Calcuating the derivative gives $$ \frac{\partial(f\circ\sigma)}{\partial x^{ij}}(x)=\sum_{k\le l}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s^{kl}}(\sigma(x))\frac{\partial\sigma^{kl}}{\partial x^{ij}}(x) = \sum_{k\le l}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s^{kl}}(\sigma(x))\frac{\partial\frac{1}{2}(x^{kl}+x^{lk})}{\partial x^{ij}}(x) \\= \sum_{k\le l}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s^{kl}}(\sigma(x))\frac{1}{2}(\delta^k_i\delta^l_j+\delta^l_i\delta^k_j) , $$ and as such for any tangent vector $w=\sum_{ij}w^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}$ we get $$ w(f\circ \sigma)=\sum_{i,j}w^{ij}\frac{\partial (f\circ\sigma)}{\partial x^{ij}}(x)=\sum_{i,j}\sum_{k\le l} w^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s^{kl}}(\sigma(x))\frac{1}{2}(\delta^k_i\delta^l_j+\delta^l_i\delta^k_j) \\ =\sum_{k\le l}\frac{1}{2}\left( w^{kl}+w^{lk}\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial s^{kl}}(\sigma(s)). $$

Let us now assume that there is a tangent vector $v=\sum_{i\le j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial s^{ij}}|_s\in T_sS^2_n$ such that $w=\imath_\ast(v)$. It is very easy to check (using for example the definition of the tangent map in terms of curves) that $\imath_\ast(v)$ is just $\sum_{ij}w^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}|_{x=\imath(s)}$, where the $w^{ij}$ are just the symmetric extensions of the $v^{ij}$.

We thus obtain rigorously that $$ v(f)=\sum_{i\le j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s^{ij}}|_s=\sum_{i,j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial (f\circ\sigma)}{\partial x^{ij}}|_{x=\imath(s)}, $$ where at the last equality, the components $v^{ij}$ have been automatically symmetrically extended.

---

Now let us apply this to the case when $f=s^{kl}$ is a coordinate function, and let us extend the coordinate functions symmetrically so that $s^{kl}=s^{lk}$ for unrestricted values of the indices. Then $$v(s^{kl})=\sum_{i\le j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial s^{kl}}{\partial s^{ij}}=\sum_{i,j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial(s^{kl}\circ\sigma)}{\partial x^{ij}}=\sum_{i,j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial\sigma^{kl}}{\partial x^{ij}}\\=\sum_{ij}v^{ij}\frac{1}{2}(\delta^k_i\delta^l_j+\delta^l_i\delta^k_j).$$ We should look at this as the equality $$ \sum_{ij}v^{ij}\frac{\partial s^{kl}\circ\sigma}{\partial x^{ij}}=\sum_{ij}v^{ij}\frac{1}{2}(\delta^k_i\delta^l_j+\delta^l_i\delta^k_j), $$ which is true for all (even unsymmetric) $v^{ij}$ and we get $$ \frac{\partial s^{kl}\circ\sigma}{\partial x^{ij}}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta^k_i\delta^l_j+\delta^l_i\delta^k_j). $$ This is a result we could have obtained much earlier with much less fluff, buuut....

---

The point of the fluff is that it does not *make sense* to calculate $\partial s^{kl}/\partial s^{ij}$ for $i>j$, so we **define** $$ \frac{\partial s^{kl}}{\partial s^{ij}}\equiv\frac{\partial s^{kl}\circ\sigma}{\partial x^{ij}}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta^k_i\delta^l_j+\delta^l_i\delta^k_j) $$ as a kind of abuse of notation. But this abuse is not dangerous, because as we have seen, for any array $v^{ij}_{i\le j}$ which we automatically symmetrically extend, we have $$\sum_{i\le j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial s^{ij}}\equiv\sum_{i,j}v^{ij}\frac{\partial (f\circ\sigma)}{\partial x^{ij}}, $$ therefore, if we use $\partial f/\partial s^{ij}$ with unrestricted indices as a shorthand for the symmetric $\partial (f\circ\sigma)/\partial x^{ij}$, and replace all restricted sums with unrestricted sums, we get the same results - but the price of this is that through this identification, we get the weird result $\partial s^{12}/\partial s^{12}=1/2$.