# Derivative with Respect to Symmetric Tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, differentiation, variational-calculus

If you have a Lorentz tensor $T$ with components $T_{\mu\nu}$, it seems clear that
$$
\frac{\partial T_{\mu\nu}}{\partial T_{\rho\sigma}} = \delta^\rho_\mu \delta^\sigma_\nu. \tag{1}
$$
However, if $T$ is symmetric, so $T_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}$, there are two ways this derivative could be nonzero, so
$$
\frac{\partial T_{\mu\nu}}{\partial T_{\rho\sigma}} = \delta^\rho_\mu \delta^\sigma_\nu + \delta^\sigma_\mu \delta^\rho_\nu. \tag{2}
$$
Does this mean the first expression is wrong? It seems that some information is lost if one naively uses the first expression with a symmetric matrix, because the result lacks the symmetry in $\mu$ and $\nu$ and in $\rho$ and $\sigma$ that the derivative must have.

Additionally, should there be a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$? If one sets $\mu = \nu = \rho = \sigma$, then the second expression yields 2. However, introducing this factor seems to then yield $\frac{1}{2}$ when $\mu = \rho$ and $\nu = \sigma$ but $\mu \neq \sigma$, when it should yield 1. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149066/2451

Comment: Thanks. So is the first expression just wrong when the tensor is symmetric? Also, the person who posted the above question also asked about the $\frac{1}{2}$ issue in a comment, but it doesn't look like it was answered.

Comment: The answer to that comment is No. It can be traced back to that the tensor components are not independent.

Comment: Ok. So you might expect 1 instead of 1/2, but the dependence of the components makes things more complicated.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Right.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It's very weird to see something like $\frac{\partial T_{01}}{\partial T_{01}} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The two objects are as different as a 2D surface and a curve on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Sorry, which two objects? I don't quite follow the analogy.

Comment: I meant, a tensor with independent components and a symmetric tensor. The analogy is only as seen from the point of view of a partial derivative.

Comment: Hmm... Do you mind elaborating? Any analogy would be helpful.