# Variation with respect to a traceless symmetric tensor

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, variational-calculus, constrained-dynamics

Suppose we have an action variation like

$$\delta S[G]=\int \mathfrak{H}^{\mu\nu}\delta G_{\mu\nu} \,\,  d^Nx,$$

where $\mathfrak{H}^{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor density. If the variation with respect to $G_{\mu\nu}$, for example, takes place in the subspace of symmetric tensors, we get

$$ \mathfrak{H}^{(\mu\nu)}=0, \tag{1}$$

instead of $\mathfrak{H}^{\mu\nu}=0$ (for a general variation in the whole space of 2-covariant tensors).

I am trying to obtain the equations of motion of a tensor $G_{\mu \nu}$ which is symmetric but also **traceless**. Which is the formal way to do this?

----- A guess

I tried something like:

$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
\mathfrak{H}^{\mu\nu}\delta_{st} G_{\mu\nu} 
&=&\mathfrak{H}^{\mu\nu}(\delta_{s} G_{\mu\nu} - 
    \frac{1}{N}g_{\mu\nu} g^{\rho\sigma} \delta_{s} G_{\rho\sigma}) \\
&=& \mathfrak{H}^{\mu\nu}(\delta^\rho_\mu \delta^\sigma_\nu  -\frac{1}{N}g_{\mu\nu} g^{\rho\sigma})\delta_{s} G_{\rho\sigma} \\
&=& (\mathfrak{H}^{\rho\sigma}-\frac{1}{N}\mathfrak{H}^\lambda{}_\lambda g^{\rho\sigma})\delta_{s} G_{\rho\sigma} \\
&=& (\mathfrak{H}^{(\rho\sigma)}-\frac{1}{N}\mathfrak{H}^\lambda{}_\lambda g^{\rho\sigma})\delta G_{\rho\sigma}
\end{eqnarray} 
$$
where I used the index $s$ for "symmetric variation" and $st$ for "symmetric-traceless variation". So the equation of motion should be:

$$\mathfrak{H}^{(\rho\sigma)}-\frac{1}{N}\mathfrak{H}^\lambda{}_\lambda g^{\rho\sigma} =0.$$

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: related: [Matrix derivative of a matrix with constraints](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405495/84967).