# Variation vs. derivative wrt a symmetric and traceless tensor

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, variational-calculus, constrained-dynamics, trace

Consider a Lagrangian, $L$, which is a function of, as well as other fields $\psi_i$, a traceless and symmetric tensor denoted by $f^{uv}$, so that $L=L(f^{uv})$,  the associated action is $\int L(f^{uv}, \psi_i)d^4x $.

To vary w.r.t $f^{uv}$ , I write:

$f^{uv}=f_{symm}^{uv}-\frac{1}{d}\eta^{uv} tr(f)$, (1)

where $tr(f)=\eta_{uv}f^{uv}$, where $\eta_{uv}$ is the metric associated to the space-time, and $f_{symm}^{uv}= (1/2) (f^{uv}+f^{vu})$.

However, if I consider $\frac{\partial L}{\partial f^{uv}}$, I consider its symmetry, but not its tracelessness. Why is this? (At least this is what I deduce from looking at the answer to a variation of the second-order Lagrangian- (the second-order obtained by derivatives in the Taylor expansion), and then the varying obtains Jacobi equations.

Comment: also, in (1), why is it to subtract the trace, I suspect adding the trace term is just as valid? (and perhaps there is a convention as to which consistent with the signature of the metric)? In the E-L equations, ofc, the variation w.r.t the deriviative of the field comes with the opposing sign, so it would seem it doesn't matter which is chose?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405495/2451

Comment: I ahve read that