# Inverse of anti-symmetric rank 4 tensors?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, lie-algebra, linear-algebra

I am trying to find an inverse of a tensor of the form
$$M_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$$ such that $M$ is anti-symmetric in the $(\mu, \nu)$ exchange and $(\rho, \sigma)$ exchange. The inverse should be such that

$$M^{-1}_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}M_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = \frac{1}{2}(\eta_{\alpha\rho}\eta_{\beta\sigma}-\eta_{\alpha\sigma}\eta_{\beta\rho})$$
where $\eta$ is the Minowski metric. Is this a well-known thing in some literature or does anyone have any ideas how to go about it? More specifically, I am interested in the case where $M_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = [J_{\mu\nu}, J_{\rho\sigma}]$ where $J$ is the generator of the Lorentz group. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Treat pairs of antisymmetric indices as a single index that can take on 6 values, and you got yourself a normal 6x6 matrix inverse problem.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov That is a nice idea actually. Is there an elegant way to represent the labeling? What I mean is if there is a nice function $f$ such that $f(\mu, \nu) = \{1, 2,....,6\}$ for different for $\mu, \nu \in \{1, 2, 3\}$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Consider an antisymmetric double-index $$
   I=(i_1,i_2),\qquad  i_1,i_2~\in~\{1,\ldots,n\},$$
   i.e. the double-index $I$ can take $n^2$ values, but only $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ values (say when e.g. $i_1<i_2$) yield independent components of tensors, e.g.
   $$\begin{align} V^I~\equiv~&V^{i_1i_2}~=~-V^{i_2i_1}, \cr
   M^{I,J}~\equiv~&M^{i_1i_2,j_1j_2}~=~-M^{i_2i_1,j_1j_2}~=~-M^{i_1i_2,j_2j_1},\end{align}$$
   and so forth.
2. Then one can define a corresponding [Kronecker tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) that represents the identity on this antisymmetric double-index space
   $$\delta^I_J~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta^{i_1}_{j_1}\delta^{i_2}_{j_2}-\delta^{i_2}_{j_1}\delta^{i_1}_{j_2}\right). $$
   Note the half $\frac{1}{2}$, which e.g. needed for [idempotency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)
   $$ \sum_J\delta^I_J \delta^J_K~=~\delta^I_K, \qquad \sum_J~=~\sum_{j_1,j_2=1}^n,$$
   of the identity. For further motivation, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149066/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405495/2451) Phys.SE posts.
3. Finally, we can define an inverse tensor
   $M^{-1}_{I,J}$ to $M^{I,J}$ so that
   $$ \sum_JM^{-1}_{I,J}M^{J,K}~=~\delta_I^K~=~\sum_JM^{K,J}M^{-1}_{J,I}. $$

Comment: I think you are right. I have to probably treat the tensor as a matrix with dimension $n(n-1)/2$ to get an inverse. There is no escape.