# Variation of the metric w.r.t. the metric in derivation of stress tensor

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, variational-calculus

Consider massless free scalar theory
$$S = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g}L = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \;g^{cd}\nabla_c\phi \nabla_d \phi.\tag{1}$$
To compute the Hilbert stress-energy tensor we require $\sim\delta S/\delta g_{ab}$. I want to focus on $\delta L/ \delta g_{ab}$.
$$\frac{\delta L}{\delta g_{ab}} = \frac{\delta g^{cd}}{\delta g_{ab}} \nabla_c\phi \nabla_d \phi = - g^{ac} g^{db}\nabla_c\phi \nabla_d \phi= -\nabla^a\phi \nabla^b \phi,\tag{2}$$
where I have used $\delta (g_{ab}g^{bc})=0$ to derive the implied expression for $\delta g^{ab}$ in terms of $\delta g_{ab}$. This is correct according to H. Reall's notes: (eq. 10.31) http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/part3_gr_lectures_2017.pdf .

However $$L=g^{cd}\nabla_c\phi \nabla_d \phi=g_{cd}\nabla^c\phi \nabla^d \phi\tag{3}$$ so I could also have 
$$\frac{\delta L}{\delta g_{ab}} = \frac{\delta g_{cd}}{\delta g_{ab}} \nabla^c\phi \nabla^d \phi.\tag{4}$$
For the two results to match, it would seem that we need
$$\frac{\delta g_{cd}}{\delta g_{ab}} \sim - \frac{1}{2}(\delta^a_c \delta^b_d +\delta^a_d \delta^b_c  )\;?\tag{5}$$
but I'm pretty sure there should be no minus sign!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no minus sign in eq. (5), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149066/2451) Phys.SE post.

The error in OP's differentiation (4) wrt. the metric is instead the missing contributions coming from the fact that $\nabla^c \phi=g^{cd}\partial_d\phi$ implicitly depends on the metric.

Answer (score 3):

Let me show you a similar mistake. 
For simplicity, let us consider Maxwell theory because it is manifest where the metric hides, 
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{4}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma},  
\end{equation}
where $F_{\mu\nu} := \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$. Notice that the definition of $F_{\mu\nu}$ involves **no** metric. OK, now we try to derive stress-energy tensor by varying the action with respect to the metric. Naively, one may write 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} 
\ni \frac{1}{4}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \frac{\delta (g_{\alpha\rho}g_{\beta\sigma})}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} F^{\alpha\beta}F^{\rho\sigma}, 
\end{equation}
where I just showed one term in the variation. On the other hand, one may write 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} 
\ni \frac{1}{4}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \frac{\delta (g^{\alpha\rho}g^{\beta\sigma})}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} F_{\alpha\beta}F_{\rho\sigma}. 
\end{equation}
Then one finds exactly your puzzle if you work out the variations above -- the sign difference. The sign of the last equation above is correct actually. (To check this, you can compute the trace of stress-energy tensor. Maxwell theory in 4d should have a traceless stress-energy tensor).

The tricky part is, when you write 
\begin{equation}
F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma} = g_{\alpha\rho}g_{\beta\sigma}F^{\alpha\beta}F^{\rho\sigma}, 
\end{equation}
you are hiding some factors of metric into the $F^{\alpha\beta}F^{\rho\sigma}$ part. Recall that $F_{\mu\nu}$ is defined without metric while $F^{\mu\nu}$ is, because it equals $F^{\mu\nu} = g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$.