# Derivative of the metric with respect to inverse metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

This might be a simple question but what is $\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}$, with proof please if possible.

Answer (score 6):

Hint
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}(g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\lambda})=\frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}(\ \delta_\mu^\lambda)=0$$
You can use the product rule on the first term to get
$$\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}
g^{\nu\lambda}+ g_{\mu\nu}
\frac{\partial 
g^{\nu\lambda}}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}=0$$
For a general tensor we have
$$\frac{\partial 
g^{\nu\lambda}}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}=\delta^\nu_\sigma\delta^\lambda_\rho$$
but since the metric tensor is symmetric the individual components are not independent.For example $$\frac{\partial 
g^{31}}{\partial g^{13}}=\frac{\partial g^{13}}{\partial g^{13}}=1$$
 Accounting for this symmetry we get 
$$\frac{\partial 
g^{\nu\lambda}}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}=\tfrac 1 2(\delta^\nu_\sigma\delta^\lambda_\rho+\delta^\nu_\rho\delta^\lambda_\sigma).$$
To see where this factor one half comes from go to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149066/variation-of-the-metric-with-respect-to-the-metric).

Finally we get

> $$\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial
> g^{\sigma\rho}}=-g_{\mu\rho}g_{\sigma\nu}$$ for general tensors and
>   $$\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial
> g^{\sigma\rho}}=-\tfrac 1 2(g_{\mu\rho}g_{\sigma\nu}+g_{\mu\sigma}g_{\rho\nu})$$
>   for the metric tensor

Comment: $ - \frac{1}{2} ( g_{\mu\sigma} g_{\nu\rho} + g_{\nu\sigma} g_{\mu\rho})$ ?

Comment: I added more to the hint

Comment: $-g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\sigma}$ ?   can you please give me the answer ?

Comment: That's correct (using what I said). I forgot that the metric is symmetric so I added more. I also added the solution explicitly for later reference.

Comment: As pointed out by @ODE, your expression for the derivative is wrong, since for example it leads to $\partial g^{00}/\partial g^{00}=2$.

Comment: @GiorgioComitini I forgot about the diagonals, I'll update it and hope I haven't made any further misstakes.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here's how to do it in a coordinate-free manner :

The inverse metric is the matrix inverse of the metric, so that, if we vary our metric, we can use the binomial identity :

\begin{equation}
(g + h)^{-1} = g^{-1} - g^{-1} (I + hg^{-1})^{-1} h g^{-1}
\end{equation}

In our case :

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\delta_h g^{-1}}{\delta g} &=& \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{(g + \varepsilon h)^{-1} - g^{-1}}{\varepsilon} \\
&=& - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{g^{-1} (I + \varepsilon hg^{-1})^{-1} \varepsilon h g^{-1}}{\varepsilon} \\
&=& - \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{\varepsilon g^{-1} h g^{-1} + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)}{\varepsilon} \\
&=& -g^{-1} h g^{-1} 
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore, the variation in the direction of a perturbation $h$ is $g^{-1} h g^{-1}$ (in more physicky notation, $\delta g^{-1} = g^{-1} \delta g g^{-1}$). If we pick a specific direction such as one of the component, this means

\begin{equation}
\delta g^{ab} = -g^{ac} \delta g_{cd} g^{db}
\end{equation}

This is pretty much what is expected. As the inverse of the inverse metric is the metric, the relation holds the other way around, as well.

Comment: Maybe you should say "indices-free" rather than "coordinate-free". A matrix representation for $g$ requires a choice of coordinates.

Comment: Uh and you missed two minuses in the last equation and in the last row of the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

For a metric tensor the answer should be

$$\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial g^{\sigma\rho}}=-\frac{n(\sigma\rho)}{2}\left(g_{\mu\sigma}g_{\nu\rho}+g_{\nu\sigma}g_{\mu\rho}\right),$$

where $n(\sigma\rho)=2-\delta_{\sigma\rho}$ and $\delta_{\sigma\rho}$ is the Kronecker delta, i.e. the function is 1 if $\sigma=\rho$ and 2 if $\sigma\neq\rho$.