# Canonical Commutation relations in gravity

Tags: metric-tensor, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, adm-formalism

The canonical commutation relations in gravity are sometimes written
$$
[\gamma_{ij}(x),\pi^{kl}(y)]=\frac{i\hbar}{2}(\delta_i^k\delta_j^l+\delta_i^l\delta_j^k)\delta^3(x-y),\tag{0}
$$
where $\gamma_{ij}$ is the 3-metric.
This means
\begin{align}
[\gamma_{11}(x),\pi^{11}(y)]&=i\hbar\delta^3(x-y) \tag{1} \\
[\gamma_{12}(x),\pi^{12}(y)]&=\frac{i\hbar}{2}\delta^3(x-y)    \tag{2}
\end{align}
for example.

Eq. (1) looks standard so I would conclude that $\gamma_{11}$ is canonically conjugate (c.c.) to $\pi^{11}$.

Eq. (2), however, has the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ which doesn't look standard at all. It would seem to suggest that $\gamma_{12}$ and $\pi^{12}$ are *not* canonically conjugate.
Any comments?

EDIT: I think the simple conclusion is that $\gamma_{ij}$ is c.c. to $2\pi^{ij}$ when $i\neq j$ and c.c. to $\pi^{ij}$ when $i=j$.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question than "any comments"? This is far from my specialty but I see nothing particularly worrisome about factors of 1/2 appearing in the context of symmetric tensors ($\gamma_{ij} = \gamma_{ji}$, right?)

Answer (score 6):

1. The factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in the symmetrized Poisson bracket relations
   $$\begin{align} 
   \{\gamma_{ij}(x),\pi^{kl}(y)\}
   ~=~&\frac{1}{2}(\delta_i^k\delta_j^l+\delta_i^l\delta_j^k)\delta^3(x-y),\cr
   \{\gamma_{ij}(x),\gamma_{kl}(y)\}~=~&0,\cr
   \{\pi^{ij}(x),\pi^{kl}(y)\}~=~&0,
   \end{align}
   \tag{A} $$
   is a natural consequence of the symmetry of the metric tensor $\gamma_{ij}$ (and the symmetry of $\pi^{kl}$), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149066/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. We may write the Schrödinger representation as
   $$ \pi^{kl}(x)~=~\frac{\hbar}{2i}\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta\gamma_{kl}(x)}+\frac{\delta}{\delta\gamma_{lk}(x)} \right).\tag{B}$$
3. Alternatively, we may view the tensors $\gamma_{ij}$ and $\pi^{kl}$ as fundamentally non-symmetric tensors, and proceed as follows:

   - Option (i): They satisfy the symmetrized Poisson bracket relation (A). Only later impose the [first-class constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint)
     $$\begin{align}
     \phi_{ij}~:=~&\gamma_{ij}-\gamma_{ji}~\approx~0,\cr
     \chi^{kl}~:=~&\pi^{kl}-\pi^{lk}~\approx~0,\end{align}\tag{C}$$
     where
     $$\{\phi_{ij}(x),\chi^{kl}(y)\}
     ~\stackrel{(A)+(C)}{=}~0.\tag{D}$$
   - Option (ii): They satisfy the non-symmetrized Poisson bracket relations
     $$\begin{align} 
     \{\gamma_{ij}(x),\pi^{kl}(y)\}
     ~=~&\delta_i^k\delta_j^l\delta^3(x-y),\cr
     \{\gamma_{ij}(x),\gamma_{kl}(y)\}~=~&0,\cr
     \{\pi^{ij}(x),\pi^{kl}(y)\}~=~&0.
     \end{align}
     \tag{E} $$
     Then
     $$\{\phi_{ij}(x),\chi^{kl}(y)\}
     ~\stackrel{(C)+(E)}{=}~2(\delta_i^k\delta_j^l-\delta_i^l\delta_j^k)\delta^3(x-y).\tag{F}$$
     Only later impose the second-class constraints (C). The [Dirac bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket) becomes
     $$\begin{align}\{F,G\}_D ~=~&\{F,G\}\cr ~-~&\frac{1}{4}\int\!d^3z\{F,\chi^{mn}(z)\}\{\phi_{mn}(z),G\}\cr
     ~+~&\frac{1}{4}\int\!d^3z\{F,\phi_{mn}(z)\}\{\chi^{mn}(z),G\}. \end{align}\tag{G}$$
     One may check that the Dirac bracket (G) reproduces the symmetrized Poisson bracket relations
     $$\begin{align} 
     \{\gamma_{ij}(x),\pi^{kl}(y)\}_D
     ~=~&\frac{1}{2}(\delta_i^k\delta_j^l+\delta_i^l\delta_j^k)\delta^3(x-y),\cr
     \{\gamma_{ij}(x),\gamma_{kl}(y)\}_D~=~&0,\cr
     \{\pi^{ij}(x),\pi^{kl}(y)\}_D~=~&0.
     \end{align}
     \tag{H} $$

   Both options (i) & (ii): The variables $\gamma_{ij}$ and $\pi^{kl}$ are then canonically conjugate variables on the constrained submanifold, cf. OP's question.

Comment: Yes but then I can't conclude that $\gamma_{12}$ is canonically conjugate (c.c.) to $\pi^{12}$ (because for $q$ and $p$, say, to be c.c. they must satisfy $[q,p]=i$).

Comment: I updated the answer.